# How to add a backgroundimage to my box2d app

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I was wondering how to add a background image to my box2d (cocos2d) iphone app. I have the image I just don't know how to add it to the background without it interfering with my touch events.

Comment: YOU SHOULD ACCEPT AN ANSWER IF IT HELPED, OR SHOULD COMMENT ON THAT IF THAT DIDN'T...

Answer (score 0):

This will help: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:basic_concepts